# On computing the determinant of a certain kind of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I would like to compute the determinant of a matrix of the following type:

\begin{pmatrix}
    a_0       & a_1 & a_2 &  \dots & a_{n-2} & a_{n-1} \\
    a_1       & a_0 & a_1 &  \dots & a_{n-3} & a_{n-2}\\
    a_2       & a_1 & a_0 & \dots & a_{n-4} & a_{n-3}\\
    &&&&... \\
    a_{n-1}       & a_{n-2} & a_{n-3} & \dots & a_1& a_0
\end{pmatrix}

I kept trying and did not find a good way to reduce the determinant. Has this kind of matrices been discussed before or do we know any related result about the determinant? I would also be grateful if any property of such a matrix could be revealed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a symmetric Toeplitz matrix.

Comment: @podiki Ah, great! Thanks very much for the keyword. I will look into it.

Comment: In particular, this type of Toeplitz matrix is known as a circulant matrix. There is an easy closed form expression for the determinant of your matrix in terms of the $a_i$ and roots of unity.

Comment: @William I do not think this matrix is circulant in general. May I know if you would like to further elaborate your statement?

Comment: I misread the entries of the matrix-- never mind.